# Software to add text from file

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm working on a daily video blog, currently creating them with Adobe Premiere Pro. I need an advice or an alternative software, because I don't find a way to add text (e.g. as titles) from file.

I have an intro, a main part and an outro. In the main part is a background image and changing text (fade in, fade over, fade out). I would like to leave off all the duplicate steps to change a text or move the position (4 titles, break, 2 title, break, 3 titles, break but in the next video 2 titles, break, 3 titles, break and so on). I've started to modify the text in PS, which is a bit faster since I dont have to look up the correct title in the project, but its not perfect.

So, do you know a software that can combine 3 parts of a video and add text from a file?

Would be nice to here from you!

Comment: did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

Well there are MANY programs that do this but what your talking about is something you want to do manually. Technically you should be able to accomplish this with Premiere Pro, and I don't understand why your having trouble due to the awesome functionality between Adobe programs.

But what you're describing is something you do not want to leave up to a program if at all possible because a program could totally screw it up or would apply things EXACTLY the same so the alignments could be totally off or an assortment of other problems with how it looks. And since you are in premiere you should only have to copy and paste these "duplicate steps" you are talking about.

If its frustrating you so much that you want to automate it have you ever taken a look at the macro tools built into the Adobe Suite? It may help you with what your looking for.

Comment: Adobe Premiere has a great feature called "Script". Its JavaScript with many PP enhancement. Since I don't no all the special functions for PP, I've hired a freelancer for that.

Comment: Ah I knew that it had enhancement like that in the macro area but couldn't remember what exactly it was called. Most all Adobe programs (except flash I think) have something like that.